# Why are particles not rendered?

Tags: animation, particles

I have already done this before emitting a particle out of an object from another instance object, yet this time it doesn't show up in the render, no matter what I do.

If I have overlay on I can see the particle animation, but when I turn the overlay off, there is nothing. I cant for the life of me figure out whats happening, I even followed a tutorial - same result, nothing in render.

[image: particle system settings]

Comment: ive read somewhere about show emitter effecting it but doesnt make a differnce if its on or off, still nothing, ive also tried adding it to a collection still nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to  *Render*, select *Object* and choose your particle object, also *Show Emitter*.

Your emitter object is probably in another hidden layer and there for it will not show you your particle system.

- Try resizing your particles on *Render > Size* tab.
- The shader assigned to the emitter is the ones the particles will inherit.

Unless you´re working with another object as particle, in which case it will select that object´s material as the particle material.

Answer (score 1):

In cache you need to bake dynamics by clicking on *Bake all Dynamics*. You will find this option in *Particle Properties > Cache > Bake all Dynamics*.